# Use of external file for list of mime types

Tags: loops, wordpress, mime-types

I'm about to implement the filter/function below to be able to get control of the file types a user can upload to the Wordpress application I'm working on. However, the list of mime types is very long and I don't want to put it directly into functions.php but instead loop through an external file that holds the different mime types.

How can this be done?

```
<?php
     add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');

     function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes = array() ) {

         $existing_mimes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
         ...+ ~50 more...

         return $existing_mimes;
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`functions.php` is **not the place** to put this, you should build a plugin.

Check the Codex: [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Basically:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Site Mime Types
*/

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');        

function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes = array() ) {

     $existing_mimes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
     ...+ ~50 more...

     return $existing_mimes;
 }
```

See this WordPress Answer: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

If you really want to read an external file for this, check this [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=config.ini+%5Bphp%5D).